# Need STUN config for Jabber

Tags: empathy, online-accounts, jabber

I'm using Empathy with a Jabber Account. In order to make Voice Calls via Jabber I would need to configure a STUN (and maybe TURN) Server. Unfortunately I can not find any settings to configure a STUN server within my Jabber online Account, nor any global Setting to configure STUN in Empathy.

Can anybody help and tell me how to configure STUN Server for Jabber in Empathy?